# Which permission required when get all users using Azure Graph API

Tags: api, azure, user-permissions

I'm writing a web application and I want to get all users using Azure Graph API. Which permissions are required. Does admin have to consent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least, your application would need `Read Directory Data` permission that you will setup in Azure Portal when configuring your application.

[image]

> Does admin have to consent?

Yes, the admin would have to consent.

Comment: When you login into GraphExplorer (using Sign In link), it will ask for consent first time when you use this tool. See this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4sjMP.png. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. How [Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/) can get all users without admin consent?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your comment. Can you update your question with more details (don't provide it as a new comment please)? Please describe all the steps. Thx.